# How can I decrypt a text file with my decryption class?

Tags: java, file, encryption, rot13

I have a text file that I need to be decrypted using this code:

//Rot13 encrypt and decrypt
public class Rot13 {

```
private char [] letter = {' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                              'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

private int index = 0;

public String encrypt(String s){

    String str = "";
    //forloop to get the each character from the passing string
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        if(c == ' '){
            str += ' ';
        }else {
            //forloop to check the index of the character from array
            for (int j = 1; j < letter.length; j++) {
                if (letter[j] == c) {
                    index = j;
                }
            }
            //shifting characters based on rot13
            index = index % 26;
            index = index + 13;
            index = index % 26;
            if (index == 0)
                index = 26;
            str += letter[index];
        }
    }

    return str;
}//end encrypt

public String decrypt(String s){

    String str = "";
    //forloop to get the each character from the passing string
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        if(c == ' '){
            str += ' ';
        }else {
            //forloop to check the index of the character from array
            for (int j = 1; j < letter.length; j++) {
                if (letter[j] == c) {
                    index = j;
                }
            }
            //shifting characters based on rot13
            index = index % 26;
            index = index + 13;
            index = index % 26;
            if (index == 0)
                index = 26;
            str += letter[index];
        }
    }

    return str;
}//end decrypt
```

}//end class Rot13

I want to decrypt a file that I made using the File class.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileExample extends Rot13 {

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    try {

        //create file object for input.txt
        File in_file = new File("src/text.txt");
        //create file object for output.txt
        File out_file = new File("src/output.txt");

        //read the input.txt file with Scanner
        Scanner read = new Scanner(in_file);
        //write the output.txt file with PrintWriter
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(out_file);

        while(read.hasNextLine()){
            w.write(read.nextLine());
        }

    while(read.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(read.next());
    }
        //don't forget to close
        w.close();

    }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I don't know how to send the text file with the encrypted message to the decryption class. Can anyone please assist me?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the file content into a `String`, create an instance of your `Rot13` class, invoke the `decrypt` method passing the `String` you previously created from the file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encrypt and decrypt methods expect a String as input.

You can get the entire contents of the file in a single line, using the `File.readAllBytes()` method. `FileExample` extends `Rot13`, but the encrypt and decrypt methods are not static (static methods usually are a bad idea anyway).

So, to call the decrypt method, you first need to create an instance of `FileExamples`, then call the decrypt method on the instance. In fact, it's better to move your logic from the main method into a non-static method in `FileExample` and just all that method from main.

Finally, you write the decrypted `String` to your output file in a single line, using the `Files.write()` method

See the code below:

```
public class FileExample extends Rot13 {

    public void decryptFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath){

        try {
            //Get the encrypted file contents as a String
            String encryptedContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFilePath)));

            //Call the decrypt method - inherited from Rot13
            String decryptedContents = decrypt(encryptedContents);

            //Write the decrypted content to the output file
            Files.write(Paths.get(outputFilePath), decryptedContents.getBytes());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        FileExample example = new FileExample();
        example.decryptFile("src/text.txt", "src/output.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with the code example.